# Force libpq to compile with 10.5

Tags: iphone, postgresql, libpq

I need to compile libpq with 10.5 for using later in the simulator.

I can use the libpq in the device without problems.

I'm forcing with this:

```
make clean && ./configure CFLAGS="-arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk" && make -C src/interfaces/libpq
```

but I'm getting the error:

```
ld: library not found for -
```

This library doesn't exist in the MacOSX10.5 folder, well, it doesn't exist in my entire hard drive.

thanks,

m.

```
OS X 10.6.2
XCode 3.2.1 64 bits
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, now it works:

```
 -mmacosx-version-min=10.5

make clean && ./configure CFLAGS="-arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.5" && make -C src/interfaces/libpq
```

Comment: You can also set the environment variable MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.5 to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a question I asked while back that might be nice to have as part of this question.

[Connect iPhone App to PostgreSQL Using Libpq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678381/connect-iphone-app-to-postgresql-using-libpq)

Also a link that had the info I used to figure out how to do it.

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/09/building-for-earlier-os-versions-in.html