# How to configure a library so it runs in the Xcode iOS Simulator?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, configure, icu

I've got an iPhone app that runs on the device. Now I need to run it in the Simulator.

It uses an open source project (http://site.icu-project.org/), which I build from the command line to create arm-compatible `.a` files. I can link these with my iPhone project, and it runs on the device.

If I switch the target to Simulator, the build fails, as I expected:

> ld: warning: in libicudata.a, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the 
>   architecture being linked (i386)

But if I use libs compiled for local use (x86_64), I get the *same error*, which has got be baffled. Do I have to specify a third architecture for the Simulator? Which one? How do I set the configuration?

For reference, this is how I configured the icu project for the two different targets: [How to build ICU so I can use it in an iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126233)

**Edited to add:**

As Guillaume suggested (and [Connect iPhone App to PostgreSQL Using Libpq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678381) confirmed), I now see that the emulator needs a 32-bit build. So that's the last part: *how do I set the configuration*?

The library has a standard `configure` script, as far as I know, but I'm still pretty new at this.

**Edited to add:**

I've gotten this far, but the references to i686 are obviously wrong.

I don't know if i386 is considered a cross-compile, if it is I need "host" and "target" options, too.

```
ICU_PATH=/Users/eric.grunin/Documents/dev/icu2

DEVROOT=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer
SDKROOT=$DEVROOT/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk
SYSROOT=$SDKROOT

ICU_FLAGS="-I$ICU_PATH/source/common/ -I$ICU_PATH/source/tools/tzcode/ "

export CXXPP=
export CXXPPFLAGS=
export CPPFLAGS="-I$SDKROOT/usr/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/include/ -I$SDKROOT/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/include/ -I$SDKROOT/usr/include/ -I$SDKROOT/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/armv7-apple-darwin10/ -I./include/ -miphoneos-version-min=2.2 $ICU_FLAGS"

export CFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -pipe -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot $SDKROOT"
export CPP="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/cpp $CPPFLAGS"
export CXXFLAGS="$CFLAGS" 

export CC="$DEVROOT/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/i686-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2"
export CXX="$DEVROOT/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/i686-apple-darwin10-llvm-g++-4.2"
export LDFLAGS="-L$SDKROOT/usr/lib/ -isysroot $SDKROOT -Wl,-dead_strip -miphoneos-version-min=2.0"

cd $ICU_PATH
mkdir simbuild
cd simbuild

$ICU_PATH/source/configure --enable-static --disable-shared 
gnumake
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I got it to work. I'm putting it here so I can look it up later.

It's likely this is imperfect, feel free to correct it. Comments try to separate what's generic from what's specific to the ICU library I was building.

```
// This is is required by the ICU configure step

# must be ABSOLUTE PATH
ICU_PATH=/Users/eric.grunin/Documents/dev/icu2

// First crucial bit: specify the Simulator

DEVROOT=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer
SDKROOT=$DEVROOT/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk
SYSROOT=$SDKROOT

// for convenience

ICU_FLAGS="-I$ICU_PATH/source/common/ -I$ICU_PATH/source/tools/tzcode/ "

export CXXPP=
export CXXPPFLAGS=

// current version of gcc is missing some #include files, we have to get them elsewhere

export CPPFLAGS="-I$SDKROOT/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/i686-apple-darwin10/ -I$SDKROOT/usr/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/include/ -I$SDKROOT/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/include/ -I$SDKROOT/usr/include/ -I$SDKROOT/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/armv7-apple-darwin10/ -I./include/ -miphoneos-version-min=2.2 $ICU_FLAGS"

// MUST specify -arch i386

export CFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -pipe -arch i386 -no-cpp-precomp -isysroot $SDKROOT"
export CPP="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/cpp $CPPFLAGS"
export CXXFLAGS="$CFLAGS" 

export CC="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/gcc"
export CXX="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/g++"

// MUST add -arch i386 here.
// Also: to avoid "undefined symbol: _Unwind_Resume", add -lgcc_eh

export LDFLAGS="-arch i386 -L$SDKROOT/usr/lib/ -lgcc_eh -isysroot $SDKROOT -Wl,-dead_strip -miphoneos-version-min=2.0"

cd $ICU_PATH
mkdir simbuild
cd simbuild

// Not sure if --host is really needed

$ICU_PATH/source/configure --enable-static --disable-shared --host=i686-apple-darwin10
gnumake
```

I'm probably not going to make a fat binary, because the ICU library is already very large and I need to keep the final app as small as possible.

**Edited to add**

I tried the fat library approach: it **tripled** the size of my app, alas.

Answer (score 4):

You need to build a fat library: a fat library is a library that embed the code of many architectures in one file.
For the devices, you need to add the architectures `armv6` and `armv7`. For the simulator, `i386`.

Look into this answer for details and a script on how to do this from Xcode: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3647187/272342

Comment: But what architectures do I put into that library?

Comment: I have added the architectures required to the answer.

Comment: Ah, so you're saying that the Simulator is 32-bit (i386) while my lib is 64-bit (x86_64)?

Answer (score 1):

That's just the data library. You don't need to build it several times. Use `--with-data-packaging=archive` when you build ICU, and then it will generate a file `icudt*.dat` .. when your app starts up, call `u_setDataDirectory()` to tell it which directory contains that .dat file. [u_setDataDirectory()](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/putil_8h.html#ab03241e29fc619a4b3f7737e98aa08ef%20u_setDataDirectory)

Comment: Not sure we're talking about the same thing--I have to build the code files for three different processors or it won't run. (I know that libicudata.a is just data, I've already got that down to 3.5M).

But I see from the docs that static linking should be smart enough to prune the code I'm not using, so I guess I will try a smart binary after all.

Comment: It looks like you're suggesting I (in effect) bundle three builds of ICU, only one of which will be used at runtime. If this were a desktop app I wouldn't care, but if the app goes over 20MB Apple won't allow "over the air" distribution, which is a requirement.

Comment: No, I'm not suggesting bundling 3 builds. I was suggesting not building the data as a library, but using the 'stub' (nearly empty) data library that icu/source/stubdata builds.  Then the .dat file can be shared among anything that has the same endianness.   Although, re-reading the other answer, if you build a multi architecture static library, your final build should only be what's needed.